# Custom ID is rendered in LaTex with org mode

Tags: org-mode, latex, pdf

I'm a noob in Emacs org mode. I convert a note of my friend's from .lyx to .tex with lyx then I use pandoc to convert it into .org. As default under heading I find:

```
:PROPERTIES:
:CUSTOM_ID: title-of-chapter
:END:
```

But when i run `C-c C-e l p` to interpret with LaTeX I found ":CUSTOM_ID: title-of-chapter" rendered as pdf. What's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop the export of drawers in general, or property drawers in particular, you can add an options line to your file:

```
#+OPTIONS: d:nil prop:nil
```

You can also set the corresponding variables in your init file and make those settings permanent:

```
(setq org-export-with-drawers nil)
(setq org-export-with-properties nil)
```

I would recommend that you *NOT* do the latter: it will create problems in the future after you have forgotten all about the setting and you absolutely need to export a property drawer. The `#+OPTIONS` setting is much more flexible IMO.

Comment: thank you NickD. It works, also I change all `CUSTOM_ID:yada-yada` to `<<yada-yada>>` and seems to works well.